# How to get a list as JSON with Struts 2

Tags: java, json, hibernate, struts2

I'm searching for get a list as JSON page. I'm currently using Hibernate+Struts, I've added to my build path JSON Struts2 plugin.

I simply configured my `struts.xml` but I always obtain same [ERRORS](https://pastebin.com/2KnxzYrb), how can I make login via JSON?

**These are my classes:**

**Anagrafica.hbm.xml:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="it.unirc.pjam.Anagrafica.Model.Anagrafica" table="ANAGRAFICA">
            <id name="ID_Anagrafica" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="ID_Anagrafica" />
                <generator class="identity" />
            </id>
            <property name="Nome" type="string">
                <column name="Nome" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="Cognome" type="string">
                <column name="Cognome" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="Provincia" type="string">
                <column name="Provincia" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="Codice_fiscale" type="string">
                <column name="Codice_fiscale" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <many-to-one name="ruolo" class="it.unirc.pjam.Ruolo.Model.Ruolo" lazy="false">
                <column name="ID_Tipo_Anagrafica" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-one>
            <one-to-one name="utenza" class="it.unirc.pjam.Utenza.Model.Utenza"
                cascade="save-update" property-ref="anagrafica" foreign-key="anagrafica">
            </one-to-one>
    
    
            <set name="scontrini" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" >
                <key column="ID_Anagrafica" not-null="false" unique="true" />
                <one-to-many class="it.unirc.pjam.Scontrino.Model.Scontrino" />
            </set>
    
            <one-to-one name="tessera" class="it.unirc.pjam.Tessera.Model.Tessera"
                cascade="save-update" property-ref="anagrafica" foreign-key="anagrafica">
            </one-to-one>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

**method of AnagraficaStruts.java:**

```java
public String AnagraficheJSON(){
        Ruoli = ruoloDAO.getRuoli();
        anagrafiche = dao.getAnagrafiche();
        return "success";
    }
```

**action in struts.xml:**

```xml
        <!-- JSON -->
        <action name="listAnagrafiche1" method="listAnagrafiche"
            class="it.unirc.pjam.Action.AnagraficaStruts">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
            </result>
        </action>
        <!-- FINE JSON -->
```

EDIT: I succeeded to obtain JSON, but I have unwanted fields like `Ruolo`, `Scontrino`, `Catalogo`, etc, and I have a `null` object at start of JSON file. How can I fix?

```
{
  "ID_Anagrafica": 0,
  "anagrafica": {
    "ID_Anagrafica": 0,
    "ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0,
    "codice_fiscale": null,
    "cognome": null,
    "nome": null,
    "provincia": null,
    "ruolo": null,
    "scontrini": [
      
    ],
    "tessera": null,
    "utenza": null
  },
  "anagrafiche": [
    {
      "ID_Anagrafica": 4,
      "ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0,
      "codice_fiscale": "123123",
      "cognome": "prova",
      "nome": "manlio",
      "provincia": "r",
      "ruolo": {
        "anagrafiche": [
          null
        ],
        "descrizione": "Cassiere",
        "id": 2
      },
      "scontrini": [
        {
          "anagrafica": null,
          "data": null,
          "id": 7,
          "importoTotale": 1300.0,
          "iva": 22.0,
          "prodotti": [
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "mac",
                  "id": 5,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook air",
              "id": 7,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 800.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "mac"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "notebook",
                  "id": 6,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "asus",
              "id": 6,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 500.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "note"
            }
          ],
          "totalePezzi": 2
        },
        {
          "anagrafica": null,
          "data": null,
          "id": 3,
          "importoTotale": 6300.0,
          "iva": 22.0,
          "prodotti": [
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "mac",
                  "id": 5,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook air",
              "id": 7,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 800.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "mac"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "notebook",
                  "id": 6,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "asus",
              "id": 6,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 500.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "note"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook pro",
              "id": 8,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 1000.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 500.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 200.0,
              "scontrini": [
                null
              ],
              "tipo": "mac"
            }
          ],
          "totalePezzi": 7
        },
        {
          "anagrafica": null,
          "data": null,
          "id": 4,
          "importoTotale": 45800.0,
          "iva": 22.0,
          "prodotti": [
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "mac",
                  "id": 5,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook air",
              "id": 7,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 800.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "mac"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "notebook",
                  "id": 6,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "asus",
              "id": 6,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 500.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "note"
            }
          ],
          "totalePezzi": 91
        },
        {
          "anagrafica": null,
          "data": null,
          "id": 1,
          "importoTotale": 4900.0,
          "iva": 22.0,
          "prodotti": [
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "mac",
                  "id": 5,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook air",
              "id": 7,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 800.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "mac"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "notebook",
                  "id": 6,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "asus",
              "id": 6,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 500.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "note"
            }
          ],
          "totalePezzi": 8
        },
        {
          "anagrafica": null,
          "data": null,
          "id": 2,
          "importoTotale": 1300.0,
          "iva": 22.0,
          "prodotti": [
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "mac",
                  "id": 5,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "macbook air",
              "id": 7,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 800.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "mac"
            },
            {
              "catalogo": [
                {
                  "descrizione": "notebook",
                  "id": 6,
                  "prodotti": [
                    null
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "descrizione": "asus",
              "id": 6,
              "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
              "nPezziVenduti": 1,
              "prezzo": 500.0,
              "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
              "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
              "scontrini": null,
              "tipo": "note"
            }
          ],
          "totalePezzi": 2
        }
      ],
      "tessera": {
        "anagrafica": null,
        "id": 4,
        "n_tessera": 12,
        "punti": 5.0
      },
      "utenza": {
        "anagrafica": null,
        "password": "admin",
        "stato_Utenza": "attiva",
        "username": "admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "ID_Anagrafica": 5,
      "ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0,
      "codice_fiscale": "boh",
      "cognome": "fiore",
      "nome": "fiore",
      "provincia": "rm",
      "ruolo": {
        "anagrafiche": [
          null
        ],
        "descrizione": "Proprietario",
        "id": 1
      },
      "scontrini": [
        
      ],
      "tessera": {
        "anagrafica": null,
        "id": 5,
        "n_tessera": 200,
        "punti": 0.0
      },
      "utenza": {
        "anagrafica": null,
        "password": "fiore",
        "stato_Utenza": "disattiva",
        "username": "fiore"
      }
    }
  ],
  "codice_fiscale": null,
  "cognome": null,
  "idRuolo": 0,
  "nome": null,
  "provincia": null,
  "ruoli": [
    {
      "anagrafiche": [
        
      ],
      "descrizione": "CapoMastrogiulia Gioia",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "anagrafiche": [
        {
          "ID_Anagrafica": 4,
          "ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0,
          "codice_fiscale": "123123",
          "cognome": "prova",
          "nome": "manlio",
          "provincia": "r",
          "ruolo": null,
          "scontrini": [
            {
              "anagrafica": null,
              "data": null,
              "id": 2,
              "importoTotale": 1300.0,
              "iva": 22.0,
              "prodotti": [
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "notebook",
                      "id": 6,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "asus",
                  "id": 6,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 500.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "note"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "mac",
                      "id": 5,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook air",
                  "id": 7,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 800.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "mac"
                }
              ],
              "totalePezzi": 2
            },
            {
              "anagrafica": null,
              "data": null,
              "id": 3,
              "importoTotale": 6300.0,
              "iva": 22.0,
              "prodotti": [
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook pro",
                  "id": 8,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 1000.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 500.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 200.0,
                  "scontrini": [
                    null
                  ],
                  "tipo": "mac"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "notebook",
                      "id": 6,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "asus",
                  "id": 6,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 500.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "note"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "mac",
                      "id": 5,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook air",
                  "id": 7,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 800.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "mac"
                }
              ],
              "totalePezzi": 7
            },
            {
              "anagrafica": null,
              "data": null,
              "id": 4,
              "importoTotale": 45800.0,
              "iva": 22.0,
              "prodotti": [
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "notebook",
                      "id": 6,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "asus",
                  "id": 6,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 500.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "note"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "mac",
                      "id": 5,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook air",
                  "id": 7,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 800.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "mac"
                }
              ],
              "totalePezzi": 91
            },
            {
              "anagrafica": null,
              "data": null,
              "id": 1,
              "importoTotale": 4900.0,
              "iva": 22.0,
              "prodotti": [
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "notebook",
                      "id": 6,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "asus",
                  "id": 6,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 500.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "note"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "mac",
                      "id": 5,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook air",
                  "id": 7,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 800.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "mac"
                }
              ],
              "totalePezzi": 8
            },
            {
              "anagrafica": null,
              "data": null,
              "id": 7,
              "importoTotale": 1300.0,
              "iva": 22.0,
              "prodotti": [
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "notebook",
                      "id": 6,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "asus",
                  "id": 6,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 500.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "note"
                },
                {
                  "catalogo": [
                    {
                      "descrizione": "mac",
                      "id": 5,
                      "prodotti": [
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "descrizione": "macbook air",
                  "id": 7,
                  "nPezziDisponbili": 1,
                  "nPezziVenduti": 1,
                  "prezzo": 800.0,
                  "prezzoAcquistato": 10.0,
                  "prezzoScontato": 10.0,
                  "scontrini": null,
                  "tipo": "mac"
                }
              ],
              "totalePezzi": 2
            }
          ],
          "tessera": {
            "anagrafica": null,
            "id": 4,
            "n_tessera": 12,
            "punti": 5.0
          },
          "utenza": {
            "anagrafica": null,
            "password": "admin",
            "stato_Utenza": "attiva",
            "username": "admin"
          }
        }
      ],
      "descrizione": "Cassiere",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "anagrafiche": [
        {
          "ID_Anagrafica": 5,
          "ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0,
          "codice_fiscale": "boh",
          "cognome": "fiore",
          "nome": "fiore",
          "provincia": "rm",
          "ruolo": null,
          "scontrini": [
            
          ],
          "tessera": {
            "anagrafica": null,
            "id": 5,
            "n_tessera": 200,
            "punti": 0.0
          },
          "utenza": {
            "anagrafica": null,
            "password": "fiore",
            "stato_Utenza": "disattiva",
            "username": "fiore"
          }
        }
      ],
      "descrizione": "Proprietario",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "anagrafiche": [
        
      ],
      "descrizione": "supervisore",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you want login via JSON? It's a different problem than exposed, you don't need it at all.

Comment: @RomanC now I only want list of `Anagrafiche` because I'm logged in via browser. But I will need to make an android app, so I have to manage login with JSON. For now i will very happy if you can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can ask about only one problem you have in one post, otherwise your question will be off-topic and removed.

Comment: @RomanC yes, now i have this problem. `Login` is another problem.

Comment: You should edit the question and remove not related to this problem questions. Also post the link related to the source code from your previous question.

Comment: Edit the question and add text, not an image link for the exception code.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure json result to include only properties that you want to return, not all properties needed for json result. By default JSON plugin uses the action bean as root object to serialize to JSON.

You should configure properties manually that you want to include/exclude from the result.

**Java:**

```
public List getAnagraficheList(){ return anagrafiche; }
```

**Xml:**

```xml
<!-- Result config -->
<result type="json">
  <param name="includeProperties">
    <!-- include only properties that aren't loaded lazy -->
    ^anagraficheList\[\d+\]\.property1,
    ^anagraficheList\[\d+\]\.property2,
    ^anagrapfcheList\[\d+\]\.property3
  </param>
  <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
</result>
```

Comment: Check my update. Thank you!

Comment: Updated also by adding param

Comment: What can I replace "property1, etc.."? Now i've the problem that `"ID_Tipo_Anagrafica": 0`, this is a field of another table..

Comment: That is not available in the list. replace what you need. Its regex code so you can write the regex expression that matches OGNL expression.

Comment: How can i made it available in the list? with `excludeNullProperties` i get [this](https://s18.postimg.org/lp9lh52vt/Schermata_2017-07-08_alle_16.53.59.png)..

Comment: Replace property names in regex expressions or rewrite regexes to comply OGNL, you only need `includeProperties` param.

Comment: I know it's crazy but I can't make you understood, until you realize it.

Comment: Can you make me an example? It's better to talk via chat but i haven't a good reputation now :(

Comment: I think that it doesn't work :( [image](https://s2.postimg.org/lcrcwj9zd/Schermata_2017-07-08_alle_17.14.11.png)